# Sympy GramSchmidt says orthogonal vectors are not linearly independent

Tags: sympy

I am applying the Gram Schmidt process to various matrix functions at a given point. Specifically, I am testing it on *already orthogonal vectors*. In `sympy 1.7`, the below example behaves as I expect, but for `sympy 1.10`, I get the following `ValueError`

```
ValueError: GramSchmidt: vector set not linearly independent
```

This does not make sense to me because I can manually check that the vectors I am passing are pairwise orthogonal, and thus linearly independent and even `sympy` agrees they have dot products equal to zero. Both examples work, as I said, under `sympy 1.7` but not `sympy 1.10`.

```
from sympy import *
x,y,a,b = symbols("x y a b", real=True)
Q = Matrix([[-2*x/a**2, -a**2*y/(b**2*x), a**2*b**4*x/(2*a**4*y**2+2*b**4*x**2)], [-2*y/b**2, 1, a**4*b**2*y/(2*a**4*y**2+2*b**4*x**2)], [1, 0, 1]])
print(Q)

print("Checking orthogonality:")
print(Q[:,0].dot(Q[:,1]))
print(simplify(Q[:,0].dot(Q[:,2])))
print(simplify(Q[:,1].dot(Q[:,2])))

print("Correct expected behavior for simple example:")
print(GramSchmidt([Matrix([1,0,0]), Matrix([0,1,0]), Matrix([0,0,1])]))

print("ValueError for my example:")
gs = GramSchmidt([Q[:,0], Q[:, 1], Q[:, 2]])
```

**My question:**
Does anyone know the reason for this discrepancy? Am I making some obvious mistake or is this a bug with `sympy 1.10`?

I need to use 1.10 because I need to call `Matrix.singular_value_decomposition()` later so I cannot simply just stay with 1.7. I noticed if I pass the rows, this `ValueError` does not arise, but the orthogonalization takes forever, and is also not the set of vectors I want to orthogonalize anyway. I am pretty confused by this discrepancy so I haven't much of a guess as to how to fix it or what is causing it, especially since it behaves as expected for simpler examples. Any help or comments would be greatly appreciated, since I am somewhat new to `sympy`.